# How to recover MYSQL tables

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

By accidentally I have check all tables form phpmydamin and  click on drop I loss all tables from my database can you please help me to recover this .

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have backups, say goodbye to your data.

Answer (score 1):

Reload from your backups.

You do have backups right...

Comment: How much data did you lose? You *might* be able to use a file recovery program to get the tables back, but you would still have to rebuild and reassign all permissions.

Comment: @banjali then you're screwed. When phpMyAdmin asked "Are you sure? The operation is irreversible!", it really meant it, it IS irreversible.

Comment: oooh shat :( but may be any way of recovery